# How to pass the button text dynamically to a vba function

Tags: vba, button, text

How to pass the button text dynamically to a vba function ?
E.g, I have a button with text ''

```
Sub Status()
   Dim ButtonText As String
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
            .AutoFilter 3, "=<button-text>"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: what sort of button is it? Is it form control or an activex control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a Forms button:

```
Sub Status()
    Dim shp As Shape, ButtonText As String

    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    ButtonText = shp.OLEFormat.Object.Caption

    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter 3, "=" & ButtonText

End Sub
```